# gulp watch only runs twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm in the process of switching from grunt to gulp.  This was working find under grunt (mentioning in case it helps).

With the gulpfile below my test task (mocha) is successfully run when a file changes, but it only works twice.  If I change another file, the task will run, but successive changes to the same file don't trigger a run.  In other words:

- touch file A, task runs
- touch file A again, task runs
- touch file A again, task doesn't run
- touch file B, task runs
- touch file B again, task doesn't run

The test passes and the only output I see is the gulp start/stop  (i.e. I'm not seeing any errors that would break the watch)

OSX 10.10.3 / gulp 3.9.0

My gulpfile:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var mocha = require('gulp-mocha');

gulp.task('test', function() {
    gulp.src('test/unit/**/*.js')
        .pipe(mocha());
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('lib/**/*.js', ['test']);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I was using sinon.useFakeTimer in a few of my tests.  Never restored the original clock behavior.  For some reason grunt wasn't affected by this.  I restored the clocks, and now things are happy

Answer (score 1):

It's really weird and I don't know why but the same thing happened to me and it started working once I started watching the test files too. Maybe it will work in your case. Give it a try.

```
gulp.task('watch', ['test'], function() {
    gulp.watch(['lib/**/*.js', 'test/unit/**/*.js'], ['test']);
});
```